# Thin film interference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, interference

There is a light wave that travels through a thin film of oil (index of refraction is $1.25$) of thickness $d$.  The total length of this "portion" of the wave in oil would be

$\Delta x = d$

If this same "portion" of wave were to travel through air ($n=1.00$) with same frequency (but obviously different speed and wavelength), instead of having a total length of $d$, it would have a total length of $d\cdot n_{oil}$.

$\Delta x = d\cdot n_{oil}$

I am curious about what would happen if we were to allow this same portion of wave to travel in water ($n=1.33$) instead.  I am confused about what would its length be.  Would the following be correct?

$\Delta x = d\cdot \frac{n_{oil}}{n_{water}}$

I have arrived to this formula like this:

$\frac{\Delta x_{water}}{v_{water}}=\frac{\Delta x_{oil}}{v_{oil}}$

$\Delta x_{water}=\frac{\Delta x_{oil} \cdot v_{water}}{v_{oil}}$

Since we know that by definition of index of refraction,

$n = \frac{v_{vacuum}}{v_{meterial}}$

We can substitute and get:

$\Delta x_{water}=\frac{\Delta x_{oil} \cdot n_{oil}}{n_{water}}$

$\Delta x_{water}= d \cdot \frac{n_{oil}}{n_{water}}$

The problem with this approach is that I've made the assumption in the beginning that the time required to travel through water is the same as the time required to travel through oil.  Is that true?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand the definition of refractive index? Based on it, try and show us what you can work out yourself. Ta.

Comment: I've added my work for the second part, but I am not quite sure about the assumption that I've made in the beginning.

Comment: Unless someone else does, I will check this tomorrow. It's really bed time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the notion of "[optical path length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_path_length)" (Wikipedia link). For a homogeneous medium of refraction index n and physical thickness d, the optical path length is just
$$
OPL = nd
$$ 
The way you define your "portion" of wave corresponds to a wave that exists the 2nd medium with the same phase shift as it exited the thin oil film. By definition the waves in the oil and in the 2nd medium, be it air, water or vacuum, traverse the same optical path length, so indeed you have
$$
\Delta x_{water} n_{water} = d \cdot n_{oil}
$$
Also, you may want to keep in mind that the energy carried by the wave in one medium or another must be the same, which should tell you something about the frequency of the wave and the travel time for identical optical path length.